# Angular & Spring Boot : downloading a docx file from Spring Boot server Issue

Tags: angular, spring-boot, blob, docx

I am trying to download docx files that come from DB and backend.

I've tried to convert them back to blobs using functions . I am able to download the file but It says is corrupt when I try to open it in Word.

> My code

```
   Download(id){
    this.uploadService.getFile(id).subscribe((res) => {
          this.retrieveResonse = res;
          this.base64Data = this.retrieveResonse.fileContent;
    var blob = new Blob([this._base64ToArrayBuffer(this.base64Data)], {
              type:
                "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
            });

            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            var fileLink = document.createElement("a");
            fileLink.href = url;
            fileLink.download = this.retrieveResonse.name;
            fileLink.click();
           // console.log(this.retrieveResonse.name);
          } 
    }
}
```

> _base64ToArrayBuffer function:

```
_base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    const binary_string = window.atob(this.base64Data);
    const len = binary_string.length;
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
  }
```

> and i called this function on Html like it shows below:

```
<button class="btn"  style="background-color: #09c0a3;"  (click)="Download(file.id)" >
```

Comment: can you add code for api to download and is api to download file working properly?

Comment: Im sorry i don't understand what api? I don't use any api ...i just get the blob from the server and it works fine